# Can jinns reveal my private thoughts and feelings to other people?

Tags: authenticity

Assalamu Alaikum. Recently, I'm getting this feeling that someone can know every single thoughts of mine with the help of jinn.  I'm  also doing Zikr. But I still get this feeling that someone can know my private thoughts and feelings through jinns.  Am I overthinking and being paranoid or is it real?  Please tell me..

Comment: If you analyse the Hadith that elaborates on the meeting between Prophet Muhammed & `Abdullah ibn Sayyad with respect to Surah Dukhan, you will understand that Jinn can't fully grasp the unseen. They catch part of it and then add lies upon it before passing the information to the sooth sayer. Also there is no need to be paranoid if the Jinn. They are but a creature of Allah. And Angels far outnumber Jinns so stay pure and increase your iman. May Allah keep you under His Mercy.

Answer (score -4):

No they can't. Like humans, Jinns can't read your mind

Comment: What do you mean by jinns like humans?

Comment: Any reference or proof?